# Can ‘zu’ be replaced by ‘auf’?

Tags: preposition

> Lesen sie die Spielanweisung zu ihrem Feld .

*zu* means *on* in Englisch here. Could I also use *auf* to make a valid sentence?

Comment: This translates to *read the game rules **for** the field you are (your  peg is) at*. *Lesen Sie die Spielanweisung **auf** ihrem Feld* would mean you should stand on that field *yourself*, rather than your peg. Weird sort of *Twister*, something like that.

Comment: Prepositions should never be translated directly, no matter which the languages.

Comment: @Janka Nah. Just like in English, *lesen sie ... auf dem Feld* can both mean you read the instructions **while standing on the field** and reading the instructions **that are written onto the field** (although I guess they are not written there).

Comment: Da passt dann aber *Spielanweisung* nicht wirklich. Für den Text auf dem Feld würde eher *Anweisungen* in der eigentlichen Spielanweisung stehen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here  *zu*  has the meaning *on* as in *information on sth.*. So the full sentence means that you should read the manual which has some information on your "Feld".

You could replace *zu* with *auf*, but the meaning would then be that you should read the manual standing on the Feld, or that you should read the manual which is written on (attached) to the Feld.

Answer (score 0):

"Zu" means "onto" or "about." Whereas "auf" means "from" or "out of." They are **opposites** and cannot be used interchangably. (Maybe "alternately," in some contexts.)

In "computerese," zu refers to "push" and "auf" refers to "pop."

"Lesen sie die Spielanweisung *zu* ihrem Feld" means "Read the playing instructions *on (regarding)* the (ball) "field."

It's hard to imagine a sentence that reads, "Lesen sie die Spielanweisung *auf* ihrem Feld," that is, "Read the playing instructions springing *out of* the ball field. (Maybe the goddess Athena "sprang" out of her father, but playing instructions do not usually "spring" out of a ball field.)

Comment: "*Zu ihrem Feld*" means: The instructions *about* your field while "*Auf ihrem Feld*" means: The instructions *written on* your field. Of course there are board games where the instructions are "*auf dem Feld*".

Comment: @MartinRosenau: OK, changed "over" to "about."  And that In "computerese," zu refers to "push" and "auf" refers to "pop." Thanks for your help